# Can't copy to FAT32 MBR file size more than 2 GB

Tags: fat32

For some reason I can't copy file more than 2 GB size on a FAT32 MBR USB.
I thought the maximum file size limit is 4 GiB (exactly 4 GiB-1 Byte)  on a FAT32.
I've reformatted the USB again with Disk Utility, FAT32 MBR.
Same result.

`can’t be copied because it is too large for the volume’s format.`

Please help. This is urgent. I'm using High Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is actually OSX Finder for High Sierra.
It's a bug that they limit file size to 2GB.
I've managed to transfer the file using Commander One third party app.
I hope they fix this soon.

Comment: Instead of installing 3rd party utility, use the basic shell command cp in Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite common but although I also believe the max file size that can be copied to a FAT32 drive is 4GB. If urgent, try formatting to exFAT using Disk Utility as exFAT is readable on both Mac and Windows.

Let me know if that helped you in any way.